# LDAP Authentication Times out

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, ldap

In Spring boot, I am delegating the authentication to the LDAP server. When I'm using the same Wi-Fi as LDAP server is connected to, the authentication process runs smoothly. It logs in the authenticated users and throws error for unauthenticated ones. However, running the website using another Wi-Fi, which LDAP server is not connected to, cause the website to not be able to authenticate the user and leads to time out error which demonstrated as follow:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException:ldap.x.ac.uk:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap.x.ac.uk:636 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)]
```

My LDAP configuration is as follow:

```
public class AuthenticationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                .userSearchBase("ou=uan,o=ac,c=uk")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldaps://ldap.x.ac.uk");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My question is why changing Wi-Fi cause the website to crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not an authentication issue, it's a network connection issue.
If your machine is on a network that doesn't know how to resolve the LDAP server's name or cannot route to it, then there is no way to connect to it and authenticate users.